# how k means algorithm achieve color compression

Tags: k-means

am reading about k means algorithm at below link

https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/05.11-K-Means.ipynb

At ln[22] here author mentioned that Input color space is 16 million possible colors. How author came up with 16 million number here. Kindly explain.

Additionally at the end it is mentioned as below

> Some detail is certainly lost in the rightmost panel, but the overall
>   image is still easily recognizable. This image on the right achieves a
>   compression factor of around 1 million! While this is an interesting
>   application of k-means, there are certainly better way to compress
>   information in images. But the example shows the power of thinking
>   outside of the box with unsupervised methods like k-means.

How compression is done here as we are still using data of shape (273280, 3) after compression. How compression of 1 million is achieved.

Comment: _"How author came up with 16 million number here"_ 24-bit color means 2**24 possible colors, i.e. 16,777,216.

Comment: _"How compression is done here"_ K-means is a way of arranging data points into clusters. In the case of color quantization your clusters consists of colors, and in the output image every color from the input image is replaced by the centroid of the cluster that that color belongs to. The claim of a compression factor of 1 million is a bit misleading though. You do have 1 millionth of the original _colors_, but the bitmap _size_ is 1/6 of the original (4 bits/pixel instead of 24 bits/pixel).